# Slow recovering from lock screen Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen, wayland, vulnerability

I addition to being aesthetically pleasing, I am quite pleased with some of the new features in 18.04.  However, what I am not quite impressed with is how slow it is recovering from the lock screen.  See, on my 8-year-old laptop, every time I open the screen or I come back to it after it locked automatically due to inactivity it takes what I consider to be an extremely long time to recover from a locked screen after typing in my password.  Two weeks or so ago I switched to 18.04 (fresh install) on my laptop that was using 16.04.  Unlocking the screen on 16.04 took only a second or two while now, on 18.04 it takes 15-20 seconds or so.  Once in, everything seems to run as smoothly as usual.

Anyone can tell me how I can check what is causing this?

P.S.: It is likely some people will say that it may have something to do with how many extensions I have running.  However, my guess that it should not as there are only two shell extensions running (that I can tell): `Ubuntu AppIndicators` and `Ubuntu Dock`.

**Update:**
As suggested in the first comment, here is the output of `journalctl -b`. The `End` looks like this only displaying the last commands corresponding to the time stamp right at the moment I started to unlock the system.

```
May 28 09:36:56 tm2 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1342]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keys
May 28 09:36:59 tm2 gdm-password][5500]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
May 28 09:36:59 tm2 gnome-software[1630]: no app for changed ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
May 28 09:36:59 tm2 gnome-software[1630]: no app for changed ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
May 28 09:37:00 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.61/org/ayatana/Notificati
May 28 09:37:00 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.56/org/ayatana/Notificati
May 28 09:37:00 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.56/org/ayatana/Notificati
May 28 09:37:00 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_1_1
May 28 09:37:00 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_1_1
May 28 09:37:00 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_1_1
May 28 09:37:00 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_1_1
May 28 09:37:01 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_1_1
May 28 09:37:01 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_1_1
May 28 09:37:01 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_1_1
May 28 09:37:01 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_2_8
May 28 09:37:01 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_2_8
May 28 09:37:01 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_2_8
May 28 09:37:01 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_2_8
May 28 09:37:02 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_2_8
May 28 09:37:02 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_2_8
May 28 09:37:02 tm2 gnome-shell[1342]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to lookup icon for chrome_app_indicator_2_8
May 28 09:37:06 tm2 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1342]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keys
May 28 09:37:07 tm2 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1342]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keys
```

Unfortunately, I do not know what I am looking for.  I note that this time it took about 8 to 10 s to unlock.

Also, I did `dmesg | grep error` and here is what I see:

```
[    5.462658] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    6.824954] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
```

In the latter, I do not see anything that could potentially trigger the delay.  Mind you though, I do not know how to read the whole output of `dmesg`.

**Update 2:**

I am NOT using Wayland as very often when I use it the computer freezes.  I only use it when I need to use the overhead projector otherwise I cannot get the second monitor (and the main monitor goes black until I unplug the VGA cable).

One more thing that I noted is that when it takes very long time and I do `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F1` I go to a terminal message window where I can actually see my password as I typed it as the last line in the output. This is now a very severe security vulnerability issue in my system.

Comment: Mine only takes a second in both Unity and Gnome desktops on 18.04. Lock the screen, then unlock it, go to the terminal, type `journalctl -b`, press the `End` key and look for message(s) that might indicate the delay. Additionally after unlocking you can type `dmesg` and see if errors appear there.

Comment: I'm experiencing this too, and I'm wondering if this is an issue introduced in a more recent update? It wasn't an issue when I first installed 18.04.

Comment: Same issue here. I hate that.

Comment: Same problem on fresh install, some times take 10-20 seconds till desktop shows up.

Comment: Same issue here. Is there any way to just get rid of the lock screen and just have the screen go black like it used to? I have already told it not to log me out or ask for a password but I still get that utterly pointless splashscreen with an image and a time on it, and then I have to wait for that to go away! I don't have an old computer but I have a very cheap computer.

Comment: Even on fast computers, this [bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/757), is so annoying.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is [bug #1774188](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1774188). Sorry--there is no fix or work-around available at time. If you go say it effects you, it may get more attention from the developers.

Comment: Thanks.  I have added my name to the list.  I have not had the chance to install 18.10 but wondering if the issue persists there are well.

Comment: I submitted a bug upstream [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/757).